# Pass extra parameters with new tab Extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs

​To add a grid, I have this code. How I ​​​pass extra parameters to 'myGrid'?

```
tabPanel.add({ xtype : 'myGrid' });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? What kind of parameters are you looking to pass?  Has `myGrid` been defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can pass parameters and other properties like this:

```
var addGrid=function (store){
    tabPanel.add({
        xtype: 'myGrid',
        autoScroll: true,
        **store: store, //parameter** 
        columns: [{
            text: 'Company',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'company'
        }, {
            text: 'Price',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'price'
        }],
        viewConfig: {
            autoFit: true
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a value to the grid with this syntax

var grid = Ext.create('{NAMESPACE PATH HERE}.view.myGrid', { id: id});
tabPanel.add(grid);